# How to get the Request Object from a Model using Zend Framework.

Tags: zend-framework, parameters, model

Is there anyway that I can get the request params directly from the model in zend framework? I need it for a constructor, so it doesn't actually need contact with the database.
In a controller it's easy to get the request... Something like `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');` but in a model that won't work obviously. I just need to get an instance of the controller, and then I can call the `getRequest()->getParam('id')` methods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes there is, but you are doing it wrong.
For the purposes of answering the question this is how you do it....(but don't). You should pass the param to your model, rather than getting the param.

### How to get the Request from **Anywhere**

```
> $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
> $fc->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

### But how you should be doing it (Assuming within controller context)

```
$model = new Model();
$model->getItemById( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') );
```

Comment: yes that's it, thank you. but i need to do this, even tho i know it's bad for the MVC. there are too many places i'm using this.

Comment: Okay, well rather than access the get Param, consider using Zend_Registry instead, that would be the lesser of two evils.